# Suggestion to automate the process of selling a collection at Opensea

Tags: nft, opensea

I mint a collection of nft at opensea for myself (5000 nft). now i want to sell the minted collection form Opensea - and for each nft i have to click "sell" and enter the price and period. for 5000 nft this is a very long time. Who has a script for automation?
or suggest other options? my telegram: @karlos092

Answer (score 0):

Bryan Bassett has a Python script on github that is as recent as a month ago.
His instructions and walk-through are in the Readme and are clear and understandable.

https://github.com/bryanbassett/bulk-list-for-sale-nft

As long as Opensea has not modified list item form in the last month you should be good to go!

Congrats!

(and Thank You Bryan!)

-Michelle

Comment: write me on telegram, I want to ask you something else
@karlos092